Read CSV using LINQ - Index out of Bounds
My .csv is in the format -
Group No,Group Name,Type,Class,Category,Description,Product,Quantity,Stock,Id,Name
1,B,X,Y,Table,Wooden Table,Table,12,50,123,XYZ

I am trying to read this .csv using the following LINQ -
var data = lines
                .Select((line, index) => new { Line = line, Index = index + 1 }) // capture line number
                .Skip(1) // skip header
                .Select(x => x.Line.Split(',').Select(field => field.Trim()).ToArray()
                .Select(fields => new {
                    grpNo = fields[0],
                    product = fields[6],
                    Qty = fields[7],
                    stock = fields[8],
                    ID = fields[9],
                    Name = fields[10],
                    LineIndex = x.Index
                })).ToList();

The issue is that this LINQ is not giving me any results. I debugged this LINQ step by step so I found out  that till this portion my LINQ is working fine and I can see the data -
var data = lines
                .Select((line, index) => new { Line = line, Index = index + 1 }) // capture line number
                .Skip(1) // skip header
                .Select(x => x.Line.Split(',').Select(field => field.Trim()).ToArray()

But when I include the following portion -
Select(fields => new {
                    grpNo = fields[0],
                    product = fields[6],
                    Qty = fields[7],
                    stock = fields[8],
                    ID = fields[9],
                    Name = fields[10],
                    LineIndex = x.Index
})).ToList();

it gives me nothing. Upon debugging, I found out that in the data variable, it says, index out of bounds of the array
But I rechecked it and I know I am using proper index numbers for every field.
I even removed everything and checked for  grpNo = fields[0], it gave me the same message "Index out of Bounds".
Please suggest. Thank you!

Does any data in the csv contain a comma that is not meant to be a delimiter?

No there is no comma in the data.

This may just be a typo, you may have missed a parenthesis and are confusing yourself with your formatting.  When you debug, observe the value of fields in that errant .Select() operation.  If I test with the data shown (and remove .Skip(1) since the data shown has only one line), fields shows a value of "Group No".  Which indeed does not have indexes 8, 9, or 10 so they are out of range.

As an aside... Using an existing CSV library is probably a good idea here.

unless the files are very very standardized I'd suggest using a library as well.  You might also have a Byte-Order-Marker at play here.  Some of the csv parsing rules can also get pretty complicated.  Quoted values, single/double quotes, escapes, soft/hard line breaks, etc... etc... the standards aren't always followed in exactly the same way especially for csv's exported from applications.  You should also write parsing rules in a way that doesn't presume an indexed value exists.  (read lengths/counts)

You should also know that you can end up with lines that have a different number of fields.  It's best to first parse the whole file to find the line with the highest number of fields and use that number of fields to make space for all data in whatever the output format will be.  Nulls/empty would become blanks.

You have your parentheses around the wrong part in your last clause so it's causing problems. Structurally, your query to process the CSV file looks fine.
...
.Select(x => x.Line.Split(',').Select(field => field.Trim()).ToArray() // <- select not closed
.Select(fields => new {
    grpNo = fields[0],
    product = fields[6],
    Qty = fields[7],
    stock = fields[8],
    ID = fields[9],
    Name = fields[10],
    LineIndex = x.Index
})).ToList();

Your final Select() call is on the individual row, not the set of rows that you parsed. I can see why you probably did this, you needed access to the index. But you just needed to take the intermediate step first to build the row and include the index, then put the fields in their expected names.
.Select(x => new
{
    Row = x.Line.Split(',').Select(field => field.Trim()).ToArray(),
    x.Index,
})
.Select(x => new
{
    grpNo = x.Row[0],
    product = x.Row[6],
    Qty = x.Row[7],
    stock = x.Row[8],
    ID = x.Row[9],
    Name = x.Row[10],
    LineIndex = x.Index
})
.ToList();

